# pgAdmin 4 in Windows 7 login credentials

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have installed pgAdmin 4 in Windows 7 Desktop and wants this to allow my laptop to connect pgadmin 4. So have enabled server mode and now the login screen appeas but what is the email and password? During installation there is no option for server mode!

Where form I would set up the users in server mode for windows?

[pgadmin 4 user login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Xe7.png)

[server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDnIH.png)

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to enable Server Mode, but for this I need to set up user accounts... And I can't find the touted "user management dialog". It would seem that to set user accounts, I need to be in server mode!

Comment: Did you install postgresql ?

Comment: Use PostgreSQL CLI for initial setup, you will get the complete form one line at a time

Answer (score 1):

Confronted to this problem, I managed to re-configure the PgAdmin instance to server mode by drawing inspiration from this tutorial and ignoring the "Apache mod_wsgi" parts:

https://www.solvista.nl/2019/04/13/server-deployment-pgadmin-4-5-on-windows-server-2019-and-apache-with-mod_wsgi/

However, it was not entirely without problems: my instance of the PgAdmin venv didn't have a console version of Python.exe, so I had to copy it from another Python install.

Once this obstacle is past, you can run the `setup.py` from the venv, and it prompts you for the "first" username and password from which you can create other users.

Answer (score 0):

### Default Passwords:

Depend on the version of PostgreSQL you installed. List of possible usernames and passwords:

**Usernames:** `postgres` , `openpgsvc`

**Password:** blank , `sa` , `root11`

### To locate your username:

If none of these work, you should be able to locate the postgres user by opening an admin command prompt and running the command `net user`. You should see an account listed related to postgres. ie `postgres` or `openpgsvc`.

Once you find the account listed, simply change the password by running `net user <username> *`

### If you cannot find a postgres account:

Postgres may not have been installed with a service account. You may need to run the installer with the `--serviceaccount postgres` flag.

Comment: When I run PgAdmin in server mode, both `postgres` and `openpgsvc` give me `Email/Username is not valid` (I tried all three passwords, plus the one I use as Master Password in desktop mode).
PgAdmin was installed when installing PostgresSQL with the EDB installer. Do these command-line options work with this installer? Or do I need a specific installer for PgAdmin?

Comment: I tried the command-line argument on the EDB PostgreSQL installer, but server-mode PgAdmin still gives me the same error for `postgres`

Comment: @Medinoc Have you tried running `net user` in a regular Windows command prompt to see if any postgres sounding users exist? This will at least tell you whether or not a service account was created during installation.

Comment: `net user` did not list any account that looks PostgreSQL- or PgAdmin-related.
I re-installed PgAdmin using the standalone PgAdmin installer this time (which still didn't offer any option for installing in server mode), with the command-line switches included, before switching  to server mode. Yet `postgres`  in PgAdmin gives me the same `Email/Username is not valid` error.

Comment: When you ran the installers, did you run as admin? I don't think the installer self-elevates and I believe that is necessary for the installer to create the service accounts.

Comment: @Medinoc Just tested the 13.1-1 windows installer on Windows 10 and it is self-elevating but maybe it doesn't elevate on windows 7? I can also confirm that the EDB graphical installer for 13.1-1 prompts me to create a `postgres` password .

Comment: The EDB graphical installer prompted me to create a `postgres` password for the database itself, but not for PgAdmin which (in server mode) uses its own user list. I noticed the PgAdmin folder contains a file named `setup.py`, I will try running it after enabling server mode. Perhaps it will create the server-mode user accounts.